# React Router Redirect component not giving the desired result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to redirect in react. But is not getting redirected to the desired place.

Here is the code:

```
<Redirect to={"https://www.google.com"} />
```

Now it is getting redirected to http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com.

Could someone help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use instead `<Link>` component. That will generate for you an `<a>` tag with the required URL. `<Redirect>` component is for changing the route in application level.

> [`<Link>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link): Provides declarative, accessible navigation around your application.
>
> [`<Redirect>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect): Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. The new location will override the current location in the history stack, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx) do.

Try as the following:

```
<Link to={'https://www.google.com'}>Go to Google</Link>
```

I hope this explains!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are navigating away from your current website. In that case, you shouldn't be using `<Redirect>`. The `<Redirect>` component is meant to be used to redirect to another route within your app, not to an external website. The reason you get redirected to http://localhost:3000/https://www.google.com is because React Router treats the passed in `to` prop as a relative path, and appends it to the current host, which is http://localhost:3000.

If you want to do an external redirect, you don't need to use a `<Redirect>` component in this case, just use JavaScript:

```js
window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
```

If you want to have a component that redirects when it mounts, you can use this component which contains a `useEffect` hook:

```js
function ExternalRedirect({href}) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.location = href;
  });

  return null;
}

// In your code:
<ExternalRedirect href="https://www.google.com" />
```